# Looking for an example of selecting a row(s) with multiple columns from a grid view and add them to another grid view?

Tags: vb.net

Here is the situation dealing with a vb.net website, I have students who will be enrolled into a course. The student grid view has many columns like client_no, student_name, date_of_birth, address, etc.

There are over 100000 students so I will need to filter the student grid view to find the correct student to enroll in the course. Once they are found, the user selects them and somehow moves them to the enrolled grid view. If a student drops out then they would be removed from the enrolled grid view.

This process needs to be easy to understand and use. Are there any examples available or other suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a comfirmation prompt when you double click that student in the datagridview to enroll them?

you would hook the CellDoubleclick event on the datagridview then do validation of what they are double clicking isn't already enrolled?